# SharePoint syncing but not showing green icon

Tags: sharepoint-online, sync

I have SharePoint documents syncing with my PC but I can't see the green icon which means synchronizing happened or happening. What can be the issue why I can't see that check mark green icon in my PC in SharePoint folder?

Answer (score 0):

Update the registry to give priority to OneDrive for Business to see the green Overlay . Priority is based on the alphabetical order of the entries. Use this workaround if you want to enable OneDrive for Business to show its icon overlays. This workaround will suppress other icon overlays from other programs, and some programs in future updates may re-suppress OneDrive for Business icon overlays.

try this easy fix Out  [Sync icon overlays are missing from OneDrive for Business synced items](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3079213/sync-icon-overlays-are-missing-from-onedrive-for-business-synced-items)